# PHP XML saving changes to individual items

Tags: php, jquery, xml, simplexml, saving-data

I am trying to create a simple webpage with updates to buttons. The status of the buttons is shown to users but I don't want to use a database for something so small. I'm trying to use XML parsing. I'm so close to getting this right but it doesn't seem to save my changes to the xml file. I have been using var dump and I'm getting the outputs I expect. I am not the best with php and even with a friend helping me we are lost.

Jquery

```
$( ".switch" ).click(function() {
            var id =$(this).attr("id");
            if( $(this).hasClass("on")){
                    $(this).removeClass("on");
                    $(this).addClass("off");
                    $.get("API.php?"+ id + "=off");
            }else if( $(this).hasClass("off")){
                    $(this).removeClass("off");
                    $(this).addClass("on");
                    $.get("API.php?"+ id + "=on");
            }
});
```

XML data.xml

```
<switches>
        <switch>
                <name>Phase Two Side Door</name>
                <id>phasetwosidedoor</id>
                <state>on</state>
        </switch>
        <switch>

                <name>WIFI</name>
                <id>wifi</id>
                <state>on</state>
                <timestamp> </timestamp>
        </switch>

</switches>
```

PHP API.php

```
<?php
/*
get from jq asks for this info
finds the item and returns value
*/

$switches = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');

//var_dump($switches);
echo $switches->count();
for( $i = 0; $i < $switches->count(); $i++){

        $item = $switches->switch[$i];
        //var_dump($item->id == "wifi" && isset($_GET["wifi"]));
        //var_dump($item->id == "phasetwosidedoor" && isset($_GET["phasetwosidedoor"]));
        //var_dump( $switches->switch[$i]);
        echo $i;

        if($item->id == "wifi" && isset($_GET["wifi"])){

                $item->state = $_GET["wifi"];
                //var_dump($_GET["wifi"]);
        }
        else if($item->id == "phasetwosidedoor" && isset($_GET["phasetwosidedoor"])){
                 $item->state = $_GET["phasetwosidedoor"];

        }else{

                echo "data error :(";
        }
}
$switches->asXML("data.xml");

/*
loading xml
changing xml
saving xml
*/`enter code here`


?>
```

No 500 errors, all my debugs are right. I need to save with simple xml.

Comment: Changing the code to output the changed XML rather than save it to a file seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/vPctH Maybe the permissions on the file are wrong, and the script can't overwrite it? Test by using `file_put_contents`, and try writing to a different file or directory.

Comment: I just ran this exact PHP code, including reading and writing the file, and it worked fine. So something else is going wrong - either there's a permission error and you're not looking at the right log file, or it is actually saving the file, but you've got more than one copy of the file and are looking at the wrong one.

Answer (score -1):

It might not suprise you. But you can 't write files with simple xml. Simple XML is a read only API. The following solution might be a bit more effective, because you don 't have to iterate through the node list of found elements.

```
<?php
// contains the state of the switch (on/off)
$state = $_GET['state'];

// contains the id of the switch
$id = $_GET['id'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('switches.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('switch[id/text()="' . $name . '"]/state');

if ($elements->length > 0) {
    $elements->item(0)->nodeValue = $state;
}

$string = $doc->save('switches.xml');
```

The xml file is loaded with the `DOMDocument` class. After that I use the `DOMXpath` class to query for the requested switch by its id. If a switch was found in the xml, we set the new state and save it again as file. Less code. More effective.

As you can see I used two GET parameters. The parameter `id` defines which switch was requested. The parameter `state` defines the new state of the requested switch.

Comment: The second sentence of this answer is just plain wrong; SimpleXML may not have very _rich_ functionality for writing to XML, but it is definitely not read-only. In fact, the code in the question appears to be using the functionality correctly.

Comment: @IMSoP do you know what is wrong then? if I am saving correctly why doesn't my program know what

Comment: Well @IMSoP ... enlight us. Show us, how you 'll save XML data back into a file with the PHP SimpleXML API.

Comment: Sure, you can write a `SimpleXMLElement` with the `asXML` method into a file. In this point you 're absolutely right. But this won 't resolve the original issue. In any case it 's better to use the full DOM possibilities. As you can see in the code example is shorter and even easier to understand for a not-so-savvy programmer.

Comment: The way to save to a file with SimpleXML is ... **using the exact code in the question**. As I said in a comment above, the code works fine, so there is some issue somewhere else - probably a permission error writing the file, or a confusion over which file is being written. Changing the code to use a different set of library functions will make no difference. Also, your code is only shorter because you've rewritten it to use XPath, but you can do that with SimpleXML too, and it would be _even shorter_!

Comment: Here's your code, but translated to SimpleXML: https://3v4l.org/PvfDZ The use of `[0][0]` is a bit magic, I admit, but the `xpath` part is much more straight-forward. A tweak to the XPath, and you don't need the extra magic: https://3v4l.org/iE4a2

Comment: This is sadly a side project so I will not implement till late this month so ill let yall know if I figure it out.